# Boost unordered_map - bug or improper usage?

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting strange behavior from within the boost::unordered_map library (v1.45.0).

In my class I create an object:

```
boost::unordered_map<uint16, MyStruct *> bufferStructMap;
```

Then I initialize it in the constructor initialization list:

```
 MyClass::MyClass () : bufferStructMap( ) { .... }
```

Then I try to pull something out of it using the method "[at](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id1350525-bb)" (see API in link):

```
const uint16 bufferNumber = 1;
try {

    MyStruct * ptr = ( this->bufferStructMap.at( bufferNumber ) );
}
catch ( std::out_of_range & e ){

  //deal with exception
}
```

When the map is empty, the application aborts with the call to "bufferStructMap.at( ... )", even though the API says the only exception that can be thrown is a std::out_of_range.

Can anyone detect a problem with my code, or is this a boost bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what type of exception you're actually getting?  Did you get a `bad_cast` by chance?

Comment: @Neil: I suppose the case is not necessary, I left it just to ensure explicitly that the type I'm getting back is proper. But I could certainly remove it. OK, removed the cast. Problem persists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark B is probably right.  If not, it looks like a bug in Boost.

Although...  Since std::tr1::unordered_map (and the C++0x version? not sure) does not provide at(), you might want to just use find().

```
// Save typing, allow easy change to std::unordered_map someday
typedef boost::unordered_map<uint16, MyStruct *> map_t;

map_t bufferStructMap;
```

...

```
map_t::const_iterator p = bufferStructMap.find(bufferNumber);
if (p == bufferStructMap.end())
    // not found
else
    // p->second is your value
```

Comment: You're right, this is much smarter than using an exception to try and control normal program flow. Exceptions are after all, for exceptional circumstances..

Answer (score 1):

I would rather catch as const reference

```
catch ( std::out_of_range const& e ){
```

Answer (score 1):

This code has no problems:

```
#include "boost/unordered_map.hpp"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {};
boost::unordered_map<int, MyStruct *> bufferStructMap;

int main() {
    try {
        MyStruct * ptr = (bufferStructMap.at( 1 ) );
    }
    catch ( std::out_of_range & e ){
      std::cout << "caught\n";
    }
}
```

So I guess your problem is somewhere else - you need to post more code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching `std::out_of_range`, try `std::exception`. Then you can use the `what` member to get more information about the exception.